# How to inject html-apps to ionic application?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have 3 local standalone html-apps (including css, js and html files)with same structure

So, i need to display them inside div in ionic app.

I tried to use iframe and that works, but I was told to use a different approach. drop.currentGame contains link to html like 'assets/game-files/flappy/index.html'

```
<iframe class="game-container" 
  [src]="this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(drop.currentGame)" 
  width="100%" 
  height="100%" 
  frameboarder="0"
  style="visibility:hidden;" 
  onload="this.style.visibility='visible';">
</iframe>
```

Thats work, but I need another option

Comment: The danger here is that there could be CSS and JS collisions between your app and this page, which is why we use iframes. What's the reasoning to need a different method?

Comment: Thats my test-task. In my opinion iframe is the best choice. Maybe they are waiting for me to make components from this?

Comment: You can do it with components, yes. Just make sure you handle external scripts in a clean manner.